# is it possible to making a posting to Craigslist through my own website?

Tags: craigslist

What I am trying to do is allow users to making postings to Craiglist through my own website using PHP curl. This is NOT an automated posting system, I just want users to be able to post onto Craigslist and my website at the same time. So far, I've managed to log in using php but I'm still not sure how to post the title, description, contact information, etc. I am not familiar with cURL.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is kind of broad, so I'll answer broadly. Narrow down your question (or post a follow-up) so we can help you better.

### Is it possible to making a posting to Craigslist through my own website?

It depends, there are two major ways, but most websites block these so I suspect Craigslist does too.

#### 1. Clientside

*Your visitors become visitors of craigslist.*

You take the form that you find on craigslist, and host it (the html code) on your site, but with the form 'action' pointed to theirs.

They'll probably block these, based on the REFERER, a session key or something alike.

#### 2. Serverside

*Your server acts as a client for Craigslist.*

You host the form on your server, and the processing page as well. After you've captured all the input, your server will now act as a client to Craigslist, using indeed for example [php curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

You should try if 1 works, if not, start coding on 2. If you're stuck in a specific part, post a question and we'll help you further.

Answer (score 0):

There is an API available now to make automated posts (one or more) in one request.

http://www.craigslist.org/about/bulk_posting_interface

There are two caveats in your case:

1. It uses RSS as the request/reponse.
2. Your users will need to provide their Craigslist user/pass (assuming they have an account).