# CraigsList posting using php

Tags: craigslist

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [is it possible to making a posting to Craigslist through my own website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7329478/is-it-possible-to-making-a-posting-to-craigslist-through-my-own-website)

I have searched high and low and have not been able to find a definite answer to this question.

Does anyone know how developers post to CraigsList using PHP (or CodeIgniter)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell Craigslist employs [CAPTCHA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA) so you can't post there in a fully-automatic way.