# Enable users of my iOS app to post to Craigslist

Tags: ios, craigslist

This question is very similar to the following:

[is it possible to making a posting to Craigslist through my own website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7329478/is-it-possible-to-making-a-posting-to-craigslist-through-my-own-website)

What I am trying to do is allow users to making postings to Craiglist through my own iOS app (maybe using PHP curl?). This is NOT an automated posting system, I just want users to be able to post onto Craigslist through my app.  I'd even be happy showing the actual craigslist site in my app (as opposed to building custom views) if it would allow users to upload images.  If you try to create a craigslist posting using a web browser on your iPhone or iPad, it doesn't let you upload images.  Is there a way around that?

I've read about the Craiglickr tool, although I can't find any examples or documentation on how to use it.  I'm not stuck on PHP curl or the Craiglickr tool, I'd be interested in hearing about any method that would allow users to post to Craigslist through an iOS app.

Comment: This might be what you're looking for... [http://stackoverflow.com/a/6501424/1267728](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6501424/1267728)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to post something to Craigslist through your app. You could display their website in a `UIWebView` if you would like, but the user won't be able to upload a photo. If you really want to, you could figure out how the website uploads the photo, then use an image picker to allow them to choose a photo, convert it to `NSData`, then upload it to the server pretending to be Craigslist - this is risky because if they change the way their website works, your app will stop working, therefore I don't recommend that option.